# The lazy programmers way to wrapping the vbscript/hta file in a standalone statically linked c++ exe

Tags: c++

I have a few vbscript/javascript html applications that I will be distributing online( all for windows only). Just small apps, nothing fancy.

My main experience lies with .net and java.I really want the app to be **standalone** , requiring no installation, and everything in one file. But not letting my users be able to see the code is important too, which doesnt work with vbscript based hta

While I *could* spend some time doing it all over in c++ and then statically linking to create an independent and happy .exe file, but I will have to spend considerable time brushing up my c++ skills, which are intermediate-ish.

Can I "cheat" and still write the whole application in vbscript/javascript but do something like this in c++ ( pseudo-code below)

```
#include headerfiles etc
read the vbscript code stored in a variable perhaps?
create a .hta file, put the code in that and run it in Internet explorer
get window handle for internet explorer ,
disable right click( to hide view source option)
```

Then compile this c++ file and statically link it and distribute my super cool standalone .exe file.

Is this a naive approach? Does it make sense? Yes I *could*learn c++ but if this does the job, I can keep focus on my .net applications which are my main bread and butter. And I can simply use Html to do my user interface rather than using something like QT. Hiding the source would have been nice but it is not super-essential or a dealbreaker, as the app is not commercial anyway. My point is , is there a serious drawback to this approach?

Thank you :)

Comment: Sure you can do that, but it won't hide the source from anyone. Anyone will still be able to extract your source in a matter of 3 minutes.

Comment: Uh..yes...that is true... I edited the question to mention that it will not be a deal-breaker if the source is visible, as it is saving me considerable time learning QT or something similar , diverting me from the mainstream development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're effectively trying to wrap the VBScript/JavaScript code in a native executable that would output the script to a file and then run it. This wouldn't prevent reverse engineering *at all* - it would only be a very slight hindrance to someone who wants to see your code.

If you reprogrammed your application in C++ completely, it would be somewhat more difficult to construct the source code that is equivalent to the original. However, hiding the source code *completely* is not possible: if it can be executed by the processor, it can also be reverse engineered.